# Allow user to sudo as any user in group

Tags: ubuntu, security, sudo, pam

I'm running a service where I have users that are running services from their home directories. They are all in the group `serviceusers`, and I have a user that will perform automated tasks initiated from a website on the service users files. Lets call him `taskrunner`.

I am trying to allow `taskrunner` to sudo as any user in `serviceusers`.

Now I tried to do this via the sudoers file:

```
serviceuser=ALL(serviceusers:serviceusers) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

(I realize that 'serviceusers:serviceusers' means serviceuser user and serviceuser group. But I don't want the `taskrunner` user to be able to sudo as all users. Just users in the `serviceusers` group)

So to be more specific I want to be able to run `sudo -u serviceuser1 ...` not `sudo -g serviceusers...`.

I've been trying to add `/etc/pam.d/sudo` in order to allow this. But I can't find very good resources for what the proper syntax for the pam.d/sudo file.

---

I know I can add to pam.d/su and allow the user to su to the users in the group, so that may be an option, however I was wondering if it was possible with just plain sudo.

I'm fairly new to server administration so if this is not the correct way to go about this let me know some good resources.

Comment: For passwordless user switching, there's no significant difference in functionality between `su` and `sudo`. But in this case I wouldn't bother at all; I'd just tell systemd to let `taskrunner` manage whichever services are necessary via PolicyKit.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Hadn't heard of policykit so I'll look into it

Answer (score 4):

James.

I believe you can achieve the desired result by using this `sudoers` configuration line:

```
taskrunner ALL = (%serviceusers) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

---

The line above tells `sudo` to authorize `taskrunner` user to run any commands as any user that is member of the `serviceusers` group. The related sections from `man 5 sudoers` are:

```
 User_Spec ::= User_List Host_List '=' Cmnd_Spec_List \
               (':' Host_List '=' Cmnd_Spec_List)*

 Cmnd_Spec_List ::= Cmnd_Spec |
                    Cmnd_Spec ',' Cmnd_Spec_List

 Cmnd_Spec ::= Runas_Spec? Option_Spec* Tag_Spec* Cmnd

 Runas_Spec ::= '(' Runas_List? (':' Runas_List)? ')'

 Runas_List ::= Runas_Member |
                Runas_Member ',' Runas_List

 Runas_Member ::= '!'* user name |
                  '!'* #uid |
                  '!'* %group |
                  '!'* %#gid |
                  '!'* %:nonunix_group |
                  '!'* %:#nonunix_gid |
                  '!'* +netgroup |
                  '!'* Runas_Alias
```

> A *User_Spec* determines which commands a user may run (and as what user) on specified hosts.  By default, commands are run as root, but this can be changed on a per-command basis. The basic structure of a user specification is "who where = (as_whom) what".
>
> A *Runas_Spec* determines the user and/or the group that a command may be run as. A fully-specified *Runas_Spec* consists of two *Runas_Lists* (as defined above) separated by a colon (‘:’) and enclosed in a set of parentheses. The first *Runas_List* indicates which users the command may be run as via sudo's -u option. The second defines a list of groups that can be specified via sudo's -g option. If both *Runas_Lists* are specified, the command may be run with any combination of users and groups listed in their respective Runas_Lists. If only the first is specified, the command may be run as any user in the list but no *-g* option may be specified.  If the first *Runas_List* is empty but the second is specified, the command may be run as the invoking user with the group set to any listed in the *Runas_List*.  If both *Runas_Lists* are empty, the command may only be run as the invoking user.  If no *Runas_Spec* is specified the command may be run as root and no group may be specified.

Thus, the meaning of my suggested configuration line is:

- User_Spec: **taskrunner ALL = (%serviceusers) NOPASSWD: ALL**
- User_List: **taskrunner**
- Host_List: **ALL**
- Cmnd_Spec_List: **(%serviceusers) NOPASSWD: ALL**
- Cmnd_Spec: **(%serviceusers) NOPASSWD: ALL**
- Runas_Spec: **(%serviceusers)**
- Runas_List: **%serviceusers**
- Runas_Member: **%serviceusers**
- Tag_Spec: **NOPASSWD:**
- Cmnd: **ALL**